# MySQL said: Documentation #1067 - Invalid default value for 'regdate'

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `o7xn5_tbl_service` (
`ID` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`firstname` varchar( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`lastname` varchar( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`idnumber` varchar( 15 ) NOT NULL ,
`position` varchar( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`phone` varchar( 13 ) NOT NULL ,
`email` varchar( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`building` varchar( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`department` varchar( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`problemtype` varchar( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`description` varchar( 500 ) NOT NULL ,
`regdate` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 19;
```

MySQL gives an error:

> Documentation #1067 - Invalid default value for 'regdate'

What does it mean?

Comment: if u want CURRENT_TIMESTAMP than chose timestamp data type for your column or just want to use DATETIME than use default null or any valid format

Comment: Where is the questions? Unclear??

Answer (score 0):

A `datetime` column cannot have a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` default.

Only a `timestamp` column can have it.

Change

```
`regdate` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
```

to

```
`regdate` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
```